# Library to generate PDFs with pages from other PDFs

Tags: windows, library, pdf, c++

I need a PDF library (preferably that I can link from my commercial C++ application somehow) to read some input PDFs, get their pages, and stitch them together into a destination PDF.

The pages from the input PDFs contain text or images and they should be placed into a single page in the output PDF with some transformations applied (e.g. scaled or rotated or translated). Nothing that can't be represented by a matrix transformation.

So the functionalities required are:

- Read the pages of a PDF (or from more PDFs -usually an image per page, raster or vector)
- Transform those images by applying a transformation
- Insert them somewhere into a page of the output PDF

Target platform is Windows 7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company, [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com), makes a [PDF SDK](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/pdf-sdk/) written in C++ that will allow you to do this; there's no built-in functionality to stitch pages together, but you can easily create one new large page, copy objects from the input pages to that page, and transform them if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to import graphical contents from a PDF and export that to another PDF with transformations: [C# sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/148669/ze/ImportPage-883275935). The sample linked to here is C#, but you should be able to call the library from C++ as well (we will also post a C++ sample within a week).

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: We have created a simple C++ sample to generate a PDF document using Syncfusion Essential PDF library.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/148235/ze/PdfWrapper1433437590)